# Figure Annotation and Writing papers

Tags: academic-writing, citations, research

If I had a figure like let's say imaginary figure A. If I were to use this figure, and only needed a segment should I put the whole figure in the academic Research paper or just the section? If so, then if I have it cited as follows: "I have data %, %, % and so on. (Fig. A) [Citation for Fig A. and line]" Would this be the correct citation?